# Java ResultSet Iteration for SQL Select JSON_OBJ

Tags: java, sql, json

I want to execute the JSON Query using the the following query

```
 string sql = "SELECT JSON_OBJECT ('customerid' VALUE customerID, 'customerutility' VALUE customerutility) FROM customerTABLE";
```

I need to run this from Java application and store the results in a file.

```
statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs =   statement.executeQuery(sql);
```

I am guessing the executeQuery returns a JSON OBJECT. I am not quite sure how to get this object to serialize to a file.

any help in this is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I never worked with SQLServer, but I will take the liberty of answering because nobody has done so far..

If I were in your place I would try one of the following options:

1. I would try to read the JSON as if it were a string: `rs.getString("json")` where `"json"` is used as alias
2. If the first approach doesn't work, I would try with an explicit string cast on the sql side

Both the previous solutions derive from the assumption that, if the json will be written on a file, no typing is necessary, but a string representation of the json is enough.

Otherwise my approach would be to read in the classic way the fields of the table  and then turn each row into a json java side, and this operation is very simple:

```
Json.createObjectBuilder()
    .add("customerid", 1)
    .add("customerUtility", "something")
    .build();
```

Comment: Thanks Renato. Yes. I did that already. Just trying to see if there are efficient ways, if the result set returns JSON, i dont have to create one..